# Align text under variables

Tags: vertical-alignment

Is there any easy way to align the conditions under the equation? As you can see the less equal zero condition is not vertically aligned.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$
\Omega =-\underset{\ge 0}{\gamma}\underset{\ge 0}{(b-Ax)}+
        \underset{\ge 0}{(x-l)}\underset{\ge 0}{\alpha}+
        \underset{\ge 0}{(u-x)}\underset{\ge 0}{-\beta}+
        \underset{\ge 0}{(c-\gamma A-\alpha I-\beta I)}\underset{\ge 0}{x}
        $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\mathstrut` to the second argument to `\underset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following defined `\Funderset` that inserts a `\mathstrut` as part of the `\underset` construction. You can change this by supplying a different first (optional) argument.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\Funderset[3][\mathstrut]{\underset{#1#2}{#1#3}}
\begin{document}

$
\Omega =-\Funderset{\ge 0}{\gamma}\Funderset{\ge 0}{(b-Ax)}+
        \Funderset{\ge 0}{(x-l)}\Funderset{\ge 0}{\alpha}+
        \Funderset{\ge 0}{(u-x)}\Funderset{\ge 0}{-\beta}+
        \Funderset{\ge 0}{(c-\gamma A-\alpha I-\beta I)}\Funderset{\ge 0}{x}
        $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks much better! Thanks!